# GNU-screen: preservation of screen state with commands

Tags: gnu-screen

I am encountering an issue while usage of screen. I am using PuTTY

Let's say, I am attached to a screen and execute the command

```
ls -la
```

Assuming the output covers my entire screen, I then issue

```
vim a.txt
```

After quitting VIM, I don't see the result of the previous `ls` command which is **unlike what I observe when I am detached from screen**. Somehow the screen state is preserved. This is the same with the output of other commands as well like git log etc.

Screen version 4.01.00devel (GNU) 2-May-06
Linux 3.13.0-139-generic #188-Ubuntu

P.S.: I had posted a question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429774/problem-with-screen-concurrency), yet haven't received nay response yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type `Ctrl-A+:` then `altscreen on<enter>` then retry those commands.  If this works add this to your ~/.screenrc file to make it persist.

Comment: Are there any pitfalls to this ?